# Handling UILocalNotification -when open not from the message?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I guess its very simple, but my search results just won't get me this scenario .

When user get a notification , but he is :

1. not sliding the on lock screen's notification message, but open the app from the icon
2. he just open the app after a while not from the notification message

How in these cases , you would know when app was opened , that there where notifications waiting for you in the stack ?

```
                UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
                notification.fireDate = newdate;
                notification.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnitDay;
                notification.alertTitle=@"reminder";
                notification.alertBody = message;
                notification.soundName=@"shake.mp3";
                 notification.userInfo=med;
```

Comment: Take a look at this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929274/know-if-ios-notification-was-dismiss/31929415#31929415

Answer (score 0):

As the app is the one to schedule them, you could keep track of all notifications scheduled and every time the app is opened without triggering `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` you could see if any should have fired.

However, it's really hard to tell when the app is opened whether some event will or will not happen.  You could use a timer which you invalidate in `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:`, but that's really hacky.

So the correct answer is that you shouldn't ever rely on a notification being "opened" by the user.  Instead, you should assume that if the user ignored the notification and opened your app some other way, that you should **not** do anything based on outstanding or expired notifications.